# Term query is giving null rows even if row is present

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this type of schema in my elastic search:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "mention_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "mentions": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "score": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data is stored in this format:

```
{
"_index": "globalmentionkb",
"_type": "globalmentionkb",
"_id": "ylWDd2kBUYncqPcTEE3d",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"mention_id": "GBMEN-19379",
"mentions": [
{
"name": " Mohatma Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Biography of Mahatma Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Svadeshi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhy",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhi's work in South Africa",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahondas Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatama Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatman Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Bapu Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Karamchand Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " મોહનદાસ કરમચંદ ગાંધી",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Ghondi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Little brown saint",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas KaramChand Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Barrister mohandas karamchand gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Father of India",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Matahama Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahâtmâ Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhi poppadom",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " The little brown saint",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " M.K. Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandus Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " M.K.Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatama Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas K. Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " M K Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gahndi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Ghadhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhiji",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas K Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Africian raga",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhi, Mohandas K.",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " M. K. Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " M. K. Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " MK Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Gandhi bibliography",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandi's work in south africa",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi in South Africa",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gnadhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhi, Mohandas Karamchand",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Ghandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Gandhian Movement",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mahatma Ghandi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Putlibai",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Saint of Sabarmati",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
,
{
"name": " Mohandas \Mahatma\ Gandhi",
"score": 1
}
]
}
}
```

now i want to search only those entitys which has mention name "Gandhi".

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mentions.name": "Gandhi" 
    }
  }
}
```

then it is giving null

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 0,
"max_score": null,
"hits": [ ]
}
}
```

even if we have data.
can you tell me what should I do to get the exact term from my elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use the standard analyzer which uses by default a token filter
"lowercase".

So there is no term `Gandhi`, only `gandhi`
This query should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mentions.name": "gandhi" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. The default analyzer would be applied at query time as well. `Gandhi` and `gandhi` should return the same answer.  This link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html mentions *By default, queries will use the analyzer defined in the field mapping, but this can be overridden with the search_analyzer setting:* which means that if no analyzer is mentioned in mapping, the default analyzer i.e. Standard analyzer would be considered and I believe the same would be applied during query time as well.

Comment: @Kamal, that's correct, the analyzer is applied at search time as well, but `not for term query` - it's applied for match query. The term query matches exact terms.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I misread that as `match` query. You are correct :)

Comment: gentlemen, we all missed space before Gandhi. I have " Gandhi" but I was thinking "Gandhi". I have removed space before Gandhi, now everything I working fine. thanks for helping.

Comment: @ArayanSingh actually default analyzer removes spaces and makes everything lowercased before storing terms, so it looks like you are using different analyzer or different query. I'm glad that you found a solution, but tbh it's not a solution for the question that is posted above.